# Insert ignore doesn't ignore duplicates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

This is my create table syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `ob_product_price` (
`product_price_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`MRP` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
`RRP` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`PB_Purchase_Price_Excl_Tax` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
`CST` decimal(15,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
...
`GM_Check` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
`start_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`end_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`creation_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`modification_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`product_price_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `ix_uq`(`product_id`,`MRP`,`RRP`,`PB_Purchase_Price_Excl_Tax`,`CST`,`VAT`,`Any_Other_Charges`,`PB_Landing_Cost_After_Taxes`,`PB_Logistic_Costs`,`PB_Margin`,`PB_Listing_Price`,`PB_QB_Price_Excl_Tax`,`Competitor_Min_Price`,`GM_Check`),
KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
KEY `product_price_id` (`product_price_id`,`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44603 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

This is my insert ignore inside a procedure:

```
insert ignore into ob_product_price (product_id,MRP,RRP,PB_Purchase_Price_Excl_Tax,CST,VAT,Any_Other_Charges,
PB_Landing_Cost_After_Taxes,PB_Logistic_Costs,PB_Margin,PB_Listing_Price,PB_QB_Price_Excl_Tax,Competitor_Min_Price,
GM_Check,start_date) select 
v_p_id,v_MRP,v_RRP,v_PB_Purchase_Price_Excl_Tax,v_CST,v_VAT,v_Any_Other_Charges,v_PB_Landing_Cost_After_Taxes,
v_PB_Logistic_Costs,v_PB_Margin,v_PB_Listing_Price,v_PB_QB_Price_Excl_Tax,v_Competitor_Min_Price,v_GM_Check,NOW();
```

But still duplicate values are inserted into the table.

Sample data from table:

```
brand_name  pb_product_code product_price_id  product_id  MRP RRP PB_Purchase_Price_Excl_Tax  CST VAT Any_Other_Charges   PB_Landing_Cost_After_Taxes PB_Logistic_Costs   PB_Margin   PB_Listing_Price    PB_QB_Price_Excl_Tax    Competitor_Min_Price    GM_Check      start_date         end_date creation_time
    Wizard     WIZ01_001_01            13665       13665    0   0                          0    0 5.5                 0                             0                 0          15                  0                       0                       0           0 12/2/2016 11:52
    Wizard     WIZ01_001_01            22541       13665 3300   0                       2200    0 5.5                 0                          2321                 0          15               2670                 2530.81                    3300        0.15 1/10/2017 14:21
    Wizard     WIZ01_001_01            44365       13665 3300   0                       2200    0 5.5                 0                          2321                 0          15               2670                 2530.81                    3300        0.15 1/17/2017  0:00  1/17/2017 10:27
    Wizard     WIZ01_001_01            44538       13665 3300   0                       2200    0 5.5                 0                          2321                 0          15               2670                 2530.81                    3300        0.15 1/17/2017 15:11  1/17/2017 15:11
    Wizard     WIZ01_001_02            13666       13666    0   0                          0    0 5.5                 0                             0                 0          15                  0                       0                       0           0 12/2/2016 11:52
    Wizard     WIZ01_001_02            22542       13666 3300   0                       2200    0 5.5                 0                          2321                 0          15               2670                 2530.81                    3300        0.15 1/10/2017 14:21
    Wizard     WIZ01_001_02            44366       13666 3300   0                       2200    0 5.5                 0                          2321                 0          15               2670                 2530.81                    3300        0.15 1/17/2017  0:00  1/17/2017 10:27
    Wizard     WIZ01_001_02            44539       13666 3300   0                       2200    0 5.5                 0                          2321                 0          15               2670                 2530.81                    3300        0.15 1/17/2017 15:11  1/17/2017 15:11
    Wizard     WIZ01_002_01            13667       13667    0   0                          0    0 5.5                 0                             0                 0          15                  0                       0                       0           0 12/2/2016 11:52
    Wizard     WIZ01_002_01            22543       13667    0   0                       1850    0 5.5                 0                       1951.75                 0          15                  0                       0                       0          -1 1/10/2017 14:21
    Wizard     WIZ01_002_01            44367       13667    0   0                       1850    0 5.5                 0                       1951.75                 0          15                  0                       0                       0          -1 1/17/2017  0:00  1/17/2017 10:27
    Wizard     WIZ01_002_01            44540       13667    0   0                       1850    0 5.5                 0                       1951.75                 0          15                  0                       0                       0          -1 1/17/2017 15:11  1/17/2017 15:11
```

There is no other way the data gets inserted into the table, other than this procedure call. am i missing something here? New to php and mysql, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

This query gives a better detail of what my problem is with the data :

```
select * from ob_product_price where product_id = 13665


product_price_id    product_id  MRP RRP PB_Purchase_Price_Excl_Tax  CST VAT Any_Other_Charges   PB_Landing_Cost_After_Taxes PB_Logistic_Costs   PB_Margin   PB_Listing_Price    PB_QB_Price_Excl_Tax    Competitor_Min_Price    GM_Check    start_date  end_date    creation_time   modification_time   
13665   13665   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0 5.5 0.0 0.00    0.00    15.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0000-00-00 00:00:00 0000-00-00 00:00:00 2016-12-02 11:52:42     
22541   13665   3300.00 0.00    2200.00 0.0 5.5 0.0 2321.00 0.00    15.00   2670.00 2530.81 3300.00 0.15    0000-00-00 00:00:00 0000-00-00 00:00:00 2017-01-10 14:21:18     
44365   13665   3300.00 0.00    2200.00 0.0 5.5 0.0 2321.00 0.00    15.00   2670.00 2530.81 3300.00 0.15    2017-01-17 00:00:00 0000-00-00 00:00:00 2017-01-17 10:27:05     
44538   13665   3300.00 0.00    2200.00 0.0 5.5 0.0 2321.00 0.00    15.00   2670.00 2530.81 3300.00 0.15    2017-01-17 15:11:57 0000-00-00 00:00:00 2017-01-17 15:11:57
```

For this particular product_id, the price changed only once, which means ideally only two rows are expected in the table. But the last two rows are duplicates of the second row, which m not sure, how it got inserted into the table inspite of the unique key being defined on that set of columns from product_id to gm_check.

Comment: it seems you didnt set the unique keys

Comment: I thought unique key in the create table will be used, if not how should I set it? Because now, any DML fails on the table throwing duplicate key error.

Comment: if you are using Heidi SQL or other tools, you can simply "check" it on the table property tab

Comment: m using MySql 5.6.32 on a unix server. In phpmyadmin, m able to see the indexes with the column names. Does creating a trigger on this table, change the functionality of the insert ignore statement, because that is the only change i did, before it was working fine.

Comment: The `PRIMARY KEY` is `product_price_id` and `UNIQUE KEY` is a combination of several other fields. If you notice there is no duplicate in `product_price_id`. And although I haven't checked the `UNIQUE KEY` combination thoroughly, I would be inclined to think that with those many number of fields it would be really hard to create a duplicate! :) So, to come back to the problem, in what sense do you think you have the duplicates? From the given records, could you possibly indicate the ones which you think shouldn't be there? In all likelihood, it seems that your `KEY`s might have to be changed.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena - I've formatted the table. Unique key is every column from `product_id` to `GM_Check`. Rows 2 to 4 are duplicates. But i wonder why the NOT NULL column `end_date` has empty values.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks very much for the formatting! Think that has eventually led to the unraveling of a possible problem! @Tweety, I created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d40d9/2) and tried to insert the same row twice; you'd notice that the result only displays one. However, if we were to go by the schema provided here in the question, then columns `brand_name` and `pb_product_code` are not part of the table, which probably indicates that __table being checked is not the same as the table being created__. Incidentally, this also seems to fit with the observation Paul made above.

Comment: The first two columns are from another table added to the query just for reference. The unique keys start from product_id to gm_check as Paul said.

Comment: This was the query i used to find out the duplicates: select brand_name,pb_product_code,pp.* 
from ob_product left join ob_product_price pp using (product_id) where pp.product_id in (
select product_id from ob_product_price 
group by `product_id`,`MRP`,`RRP`,`PB_Purchase_Price_Excl_Tax`,`CST`,`VAT`,`Any_Other_Charges`,`PB_Landing_Cost_After_Taxes`,`PB_Logistic_Costs`,`PB_Margin`,`PB_Listing_Price`,`PB_QB_Price_Excl_Tax`,`Competitor_Min_Price`,`GM_Check`
having count(*) > 1) 
and pb_product_code like 'WIZ01%';

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, Thanks for formatting the table contents, m still figuring out  how to format it :(. The end_date column is showing blank in toad,but in phpmyadmin, it shows this:

Comment: Wizard WIZ01_001_01 22541 13665 3300.00 0.00 2200.00 0.0 5.5 0.0 2321.00 0.00 15.00 2670.00 2530.81 3300.00 0.15 0000-00-00 00:00:00 0000-00-00 00:00:00 2017-01-10 14:21:18  
Wizard WIZ01_001_01 44365 13665 3300.00 0.00 2200.00 0.0 5.5 0.0 2321.00 0.00 15.00 2670.00 2530.81 3300.00 0.15 2017-01-17 00:00:00 0000-00-00 00:00:00 2017-01-17 10:27:05

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Statement:**
Insert ignore doesn't ignore duplicates in mysql.

**Incorrect way of verifying:**

> This was the query i used to find out the duplicates:

```
SELECT brand_name,pb_product_code,pp.* FROM ob_product LEFT JOIN ob_product_price ......
```

**Correct verification method:**
Since the records are being inserted in `ob_product_price`, the actual way to correctly verify whether or not duplicates exist is to run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM ob_product_price;
```

As demonstrated by the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d40d9/2), you shouldn't notice any duplicates with the given key structure and records being added using `INSERT IGNORE` operations.

**Cause of confusion:**

> The first two columns are from another table added to the query just for reference

When a table is used as a first participant in a `LEFT JOIN`, it doesn't remain a *just for reference* look-up. In fact, it actually becomes the driving force for the entire result set produced by the query. Meaning, according to the query you quote in the comments above, the results really correspond one-to-one with `ob_product`. And, against your intended purpose, `ob_product_price` is the one that is getting used as a reference.

**Resolution:** 
The quickest way for you to get the correct results should be to reverse the order of tables in the join:

```
SELECT brand_name,pb_product_code,pp.* 
         FROM ob_product_price pp LEFT JOIN ob_product USING (product_id) 
         WHERE pp.product_id IN 
            (SELECT product_id FROM ob_product_price 
             GROUP BY product_id,MRP,RRP,PB_Purchase_Price_Excl_Tax,
                      CST,VAT,Any_Ot‌​her_Charges,PB_Landi‌​ng_Cost_After_Taxes,‌​
                      PB_Logistic_Costs,PB‌​_Margin,PB_Listing_P‌​rice,
                      PB_QB_Price_Exc‌​l_Tax,Competitor_Min‌​_Price,GM_Check 
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) 
         AND pb_product_code LIKE 'WIZ01%';
```

As a note, I think I'd go on to say that, **if** the query stated in "correct verification method":

```
SELECT * FROM ob_product_price;
```

gives you unique records (as it most likely should), **then** the entire `IN` condition in the final query would be superfluous and can safely be discarded. In strict terms, I think we could probably say that there shouldn't be any record in `ob_product_price` which doesn't have a reference in `ob_product`. Therefore, the query above should ideally be constructed with an `INNER JOIN`. However, `LEFT JOIN`, for the moment, would work just as fine.

It would be a good idea to understand why and how this is so. Please have a look at the documentation for different types of joins at the following links:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Comment: Added only the table data which shows the duplicate rows for a single product.

Comment: When i run the select * from ob_product_price query, i could see the duplicated rows. I have edited the question also to show that o/p. Yes i did run the query in the resolution section with ob_product_price as the driving table and i get the same result of 4 rows for a product id.